# Varying over multiple parameters with scipy's differential evolution

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, differential-evolution

I'm finding the maximum of a function f over the parameter nu in Python using Scipy's built-in differential evolution, while keeping the other terms (args) fixed. My code

```python
max = scipy.optimize.differential_evolution(lambda nu:-f(args,nu),bounds)
 
fopt = max.fun
```

Gives me the correct value I desire. However, now I want to do the same thing but vary over two parameters; call them nu and mu. I tried

```python
max = scipy.optimize.differential_evolution(lambda nu,mu:-f(args,nu,mu),bounds)

fopt = max.fun
```

But I get an error. What is the correct way to implement optimization over several parameters using the above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can optimize multiple parameters by passing them as a list to `scipy.optimize.differential_evolution`. For example, assume the following function that takes a list `x` as an argument:

```python
def fun(x):
    return x[0] + x[1]
```

Let's assume the first parameter is `nu` (corresponds to `x[0]`) and the second one is `mu` (corresponds to `x[1]`). Define bounds accordingly for `nu` and `mu` and then you can optimize both at once as:

```python
from scipy.optimize import differential_evolution

bounds = [(0,2), (0,3)] # for e.g., (0,2) for nu and (0,3) for mu
max = differential_evolution(fun, bounds)
fopt = max.fun
```

Using `lambda`:

```python
from scipy.optimize import differential_evolution

fun = lambda x: x[0]+x[1]
bounds = [(0,2), (0,3)] # for e.g., (0,2) for nu and (0,3) for mu
max = differential_evolution(fun, bounds)
fopt = max.fun
```

In your specific case, your lambda function `lambda nu,mu:-f(args,nu,mu)` is returning negative value of function `f`. Here you can pass `nu` and `mu` in a list `x` as `lambda x:-f(args,x)` and unpack `x` in `f` for `nu` and `mu` respectively.